# Problems exporting PDF from Pages and uploading to Jobvite

Tags: pdf, pages, iwork

I created my resume in Pages 5.2.2 and converted it to a PDF using the "Export to PDF" feature.

Overall, everything seems to work fine. However, I am having problems applying to jobs on Jobvite. When I upload my resume using the "Upload Resume" dialog, it appears to upload, but then the file input changes to "No file selected." and the site freezes. The dialog still says "Uploading" and I see these errors in my web console:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal UploadOverlay.aspx:17
ReferenceError: init is not defined UploadOverlay.aspx:1
```

I thought the problem was on their end, so I emailed them about it and they said the problem may be caused because I renamed the PDF after I exported it. I was careful to export the PDF again and not rename it, but when I tried uploading it, the same thing happened. I told them about it and they said they would look into it, but I haven't heard anything from them since then. That was 3 weeks ago.

I reported the problem to Apple using the "Provide Pages Feedback" feature, but they said they would not be able to reply directly to me.

I used to make my resume in LibreOffice and it worked fine. I can continue to use LibreOffice for now, but I like Pages a lot more (apart from this bug).

**Does anyone know why this is happening or what can be done about it?**

Comment: I am sorry if this question is somewhat inappropriate or off-topic but I don't know where else I can ask and have some hope of getting help.

Comment: Open in Adobe then save in Adobe.

Comment: They system probably has a filter making sure the files is a original Adobe pdf type, so do not use conversion or export in other programs.

Comment: Currently, you cannot add resumes that are scanned or locked PDFs. Please be sure that the document is a Word document or unlocked PDF.

Comment: @Buscar웃, your responses are making me more confused. By "Adobe", do you mean Adobe Acrobat or some other thing I have to pay for? Why would Jobvite have a filter making sure the file is an "original Adobe pdf type"? If they have such a filter, why don't they show a message explaining what happened, instead of freezing up? Also, why was I able to upload files exported from LibreOffice? What is that thing about locked PDFs? Are the PDFs exported from Pages locked?

Comment: PDF is not PDF. So the only true PDF is the Adobe Acrobat PDF. They web site clearly says it will not accept scanned or locked PDF. Why do they have the file filter, ask them but would guess to make sure they do not get contaminated. So what is wrong with using Adobe to recreate your file? do you want o submit the resume or discuss PDF versions.

Comment: I want to submit the resume. I think it is ridiculous that I would have to pay for, or otherwise obtain a specific program that I have no desire to use, just so I can upload my resume to one specific site. Why does every other website I upload my resume to work fine with my exported PDF? Why does everyone I email the PDF to not complain or have problems?

Comment: Why does it matter whether Jobvite accepts locked PDFs? Are the PDFs that Pages creates locked? Is there any simple way to tell if a given PDF is locked? I tried selecting the PDF in finder and then clicking "Get Info". In the window that popped up, the "Locked" checkbox was unchecked and the "Security" section under "More Info" said "None".

Comment: Someone from Jobvite told me that "other resume PDFs seem to be working fine, it’s hard to see what exactly is wrong with your resume". I am hoping that someone in the world has successfully exported their resume from Pages and uploaded it to Jobvite. If that is the case, I would like to know how they did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend NOT to use the Pages "[Export as PDF](http://www.macworld.com/article/1044923/pagespdf.html)" file, since there might be [inconsistencies](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4519485?tstart=0) with Adobe PDF format.

I would recommend you use the Pages- Print- PostScript.

Now open that file in Preview and save as PDF.

Comment: Thank you. I tried what you suggested and it worked. I didn't know that about Pages' PDF export feature. Your suggestion is a little cumbersome but it is the best I've seen so far and at least I am no longer completely in the dark about what was causing the problem.

Comment: Yes I know it is bit cumbersome, but what can I say to the ability of Pages to make 101% PDF compatible format. As said earlier, PDF is not same as PDF.